# Where can I find some game management tools for Mythus?

Tags: tools

Has anybody developed any kind of tools to aid the management of a Mythus game? Anything from a simple Excel spreadsheet to a fully-fledged GUI app..

Comment: What are you looking for, exactly?

Comment: Please clarify what kind(s) of functionality you're looking for - many parts of it may be available not *specifically* for Mythus, if you just want a dice roller or campaign logger or treasure tracker or whatever. "Anything" is too vague, there are 100 things including Evernote on your phone that can fit that description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mike's Mythus page](http://www.icculus.org/~msphil/mythus/programs/) has some programs and spreadsheets mainly for player character (Heroic Persona) management.

The only other Mythus material I have come across online is the [mailing list archive](http://www.hoboes.com/RPG/mythus/) which who knows what treasures it might lead you to and [this site](http://www.babylonbycandlelight.com/darkmyst/mythus.htm) which has mainly campaign related info.